# Integration of Javascript XMPP client with Facebook Chat and Google Talk

Tags: xmpp, strophe, facebook-chat, google-talk

After implementing a XMPP client and integrating with Facebook Chat and Google Talk, will be possible to manipulate which users will be shown up in the chat list (e.g. instead of all online users)?

Also, I found that Facebook does not federate (it does not make/accept connections to/from other XMPP servers). Anyway, can I show up the Facebook contacts, and GTalk contacts in the same client (list), without connecting it?

Last point, I will use Strophe.js. However, my research tells me that I need also a kind of 'connection manager' (not strophe) to handle the BOSH protocol, what is this connection manager thing?